# How do I get ui-sortable to only work on a specific id in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a .column class element that is sortable.
I have two id's in that column:

```
<div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">
<div id="column2" class="column ui-sortable">
```

I want there to be an open hand when moused over and a closed hand when dragged ONLY on column1.
If my CSS looks like this:

```
.ui-sortable{
    cursor: grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important;
}
#column1 .ui-sortable-helper{
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor:-webkit-grabbing;
    cursor:-moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}
```

then the open hand shows on column1 and column2 and the closed hand shows on column1 being dragged.  But since I only want an open hand on column1, I tried:

```
#column1 .ui-sortable{
    cursor: grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default !important;
}
```

But this does nothing to column1.  I get a default cursor. Why does adding the id work on .ui-sortable-helper, but not ui-sortable?  How do I get the open hand to show up only on column1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS rule you need is:

```
#column1.ui-sortable
```

because you want to specify the element with the *id* '#column1' which has the *class* 'ui-sortable', and not any element with the class 'ui-sortable' which is a child of '#column1'.

Due to the discussion below I add some basic information about CSS classes and elements:

```
<div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">
```

this element has one ID 'column1', you reference an ID in CSS via the # symbol + IDname, so in this case '#column1'. This element also has two classes 'column' and 'ui-sortable'. In your case you wanted to apply CSS-rules only to this specfic element. Which you simpy could do by using the ID-Selector:

```
#column1 { }
```

In your question you used:

```
#column1 .ui-sortable { }
```

this would be interpreted as *find an Element by the ID '#column1' and all nested elements of this parent which have the class 'ui-sortable'*. No match - because the Element itself has the class, not a child. If you remove the space the CSS-Selector:

```
#column1.ui-sortable { }
```

it is interpreted as *find an Element by the ID '#column1' which hass the class 'ui-sortable'* This might be a bit overweighted, because an id should be unique, but it solved your problem. 
The element with the class 'ui-sortable-helper' is a child of the div#column1 so here you'll need the space.

```
<div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">
    <div class="ui-sortable-helper">
    </div>
</div>
```

So the selector has to have a space:

```
#column1 .ui-sortable-helper { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  So #column1 .ui-sortable doesn't work but #column1.ui-sortable does? What difference does the space make?

Comment: @user1798531 see my answer if you have a space it is read: 'parentSelector childSelector' if there is no space it is read: Selector1WithSelector2

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks so much!  But I wonder why #column1.ui-sortable-helper doesn't work.

Comment: @user1798531 can't see what you mean?

Comment: I use ui-sortable-helper to make the closed hand when the object is being dragged. Again, I only want it for column1. But for this one, #column1.ui-sortable-helper doesn't work but #column1 .ui-sortable-helper does.  Why does without the space work for ui-sortable, but with the space works for ui-sortable-helper?